# Differences between "empty project" and "external build system" in XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

I am new in the programming world, and use XCode's IDE and compiler (GCC?) to program. But I have a questions, what is the differences between "empty project" and "external build system" in XCode?

It's sounds like a stupid question, but why not ask? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The External Build System project template already contains a target for, you guessed it!, an external build system; the empty project is empty, i.e. has no targets at all. Not that big a difference, there is a template for an external target, so it's just a few clicks away.